# Vue3 - Deep watcher using getter to find element of array invokes callback when new items are pushed in array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, watch, vue-reactivity

I have an array inside reactive object called `operations`. When i push new operation inside an array, the watcher set on a particular array element gets invoked.

Context: I want to implement an undo-redo functionality on operation level therefore i am setting a watcher on each operation and because i can add/delete operations, indexes are not stable hence i am using find inside getter to return the operation

Please find a minimal eg here: [vue sandbox](https://play.vuejs.org/#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). Note than everytime a button is click, it prints to console

Expected result: As object at index 0 doesnt change, just pushing new values should not invoke callback